# npm start causing 'FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory' when azure is included?

Tags: node.js, azure, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a React-Redux web app running in typescript. Everything works fine but after I installed Azure (npm install azure) and tried to include it in a file like so: const Azure = import('azure')

When I try to run npm start webpack seems to be trying to compile the typescript to javascri[t but gets stuck at around 69% where it goes between 69 and 68% for a long time then goes up to 92% then is stuck there too.

This is the error log I get:

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe', 1 verbose cli
>   'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
>   1 verbose cli   'start' ] 2 info using npm@5.6.0 3 info using
>   node@v8.9.1 4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
>   5 info lifecycle react-redux-typescript-boilerplate@0.0.0~prestart:
>   react-redux-typescript-boilerplate@0.0.0 6 info lifecycle
>   react-redux-typescript-boilerplate@0.0.0~start:
>   react-redux-typescript-boilerplate@0.0.0 7 verbose lifecycle
>   react-redux-typescript-boilerplate@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in
>   lifecycle true 8 verbose lifecycle
>   react-redux-typescript-boilerplate@0.0.0~start: PATH:
>   C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;W:\myproject-next\DeansOffice\node_modules.bin;C:\Program
>   Files\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16;C:\Program
>   Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program
>   Files\7-Zip\;W:\SDKs\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Autodesk\Backburner\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre1.8.0_92\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client
>   SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program
>   Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;C:\Program
>   Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin 9 verbose lifecycle
>   react-redux-typescript-boilerplate@0.0.0~start: CWD:
>   W:\myproject-next\DeansOffice 10 silly lifecycle
>   react-redux-typescript-boilerplate@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 10
>   silly lifecycle   'webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --inline
>   --watch' ] 11 silly lifecycle react-redux-typescript-boilerplate@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 3 
>   signal: null 12 info lifecycle
>   react-redux-typescript-boilerplate@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start
>   script 13 verbose stack Error:
>   react-redux-typescript-boilerplate@0.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server
>   --progress --colors --inline --watch` 13 verbose stack Exit status 3 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.
>   (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
>   13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) 13 verbose stack
>   at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7) 13 verbose stack     at
>   ChildProcess.
>   (C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
>   13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) 13 verbose stack
>   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7) 13 verbose stack     at
>   maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16) 13 verbose stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
>   14 verbose pkgid react-redux-typescript-boilerplate@0.0.0 15 verbose
>   cwd W:\myproject-next\DeansOffice 16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299 17
>   verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
>   "start" 18 verbose node v8.9.1 19 verbose npm  v5.6.0 20 error code
>   ELIFECYCLE 21 error errno 3 22 error
>   react-redux-typescript-boilerplate@0.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server
>   --progress --colors --inline --watch` 22 error Exit status 3 23 error Failed at the react-redux-typescript-boilerplate@0.0.0 start script.
>   23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional logging output above. 24 verbose exit [ 3, true ]

Comment: Are you sure you tools are compatible with ImageMagick 7. It uses magick for its command rather than convert as used in ImageMagick 6. Also if on Windows, be sure you have installed the correct 32-bit or 64-bit compile of ImageMagick as appropriate for your OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the azure npm package does not work with browserify hence the issues.